# Why DATE function cannot use with count distinct in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date

Im using Hibernate with MySQL. I have the following query:

```
SELECT count(distinct DATE(s.my_date)) FROM my_table s WHERE (DATE(s.my_date) BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date)"
```

Since I use Timestamp in MySQL, I need to use DATE() to compare date parts only. The problem is whenever I use DATE() along with the distinct keyword, I got errors:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1
```

The query worked fine if I removed the DATE() from the count() function but it produced wrong results.
My question is why the DATE() works fine in Where clause but not in count() function with distinct keyword?
I can get that worked with native query using DATE_FORMAT(), but for some reasons, Im trying to get things worked in Hibernate.

Comment: If `my_date` datatype is text, then there is nothing wrong with your query except for double quotes at the end, which I believe is a typo. There is no reason that it would work without `date()` but won't work with `date()`. Try running the query on database directly and if you still get the error, then try reproducing the result on rextester.com  and share the same.

Answer (score -1):

try this query `SELECT count(distinct DATE(s.my_date)) FROM my_table s WHERE DATE(s.my_date) BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date"`.

Comment: How this query is different from mine above?

Comment: @Mayank - Whereas the extra braces after `where` clause are no necessary in the OP's query, that alone will not cause any error.